# User authentication on Android before CRUD operations

Tags: php, android, authentication, crud

I have a database which has some data tables and a user table. This database is queried only through a php page, which executes classical CRUD operations. Then, I have an Android app which calls the php page (through Volley) to read/write data, and shows data back to the user.

I'd like to implement a login layer, i.e. the app user does a login, and then can operate on data.

So: user inputs user&pass, pass is hashed, php page is called with action=login user and hashpass, php page queries the db to check credentials, the record is found, the php page sends a "success" back to the app. But then, how to keep authentication in the next CRUD operations? What are the best practices to handle this in a safe and robust way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think firebase might be useful to you as they offer Authentication with ease. I dont know much about firebase and i think it may be a paid service. Anyway you can check a how to tutorial here http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences class to store authorization token. So when you successfully log in send token as request and save it there. On log out clear SharedPreferences. Good luck